# Vee-Validate only validate one field

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, vue.js

I am using `vuejs 2` and use `vee-validate 2.0.0-beta.18` for validation. But run into problem when I called `this.$validator.validateAll()` it only validate one field. This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6auomnbr/46/).

This is the html:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" 
          v-model="email" name="email"
          v-validate data-vv-rules="required|email">
      <p v-if="errors.has('email')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</p>

      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" 
          v-model="name" name="name"
          v-validate data-vv-rules="required">
      <p v-if="errors.has('name')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('name') }}</p>

      <label>City</label>
      <select class="form-control" 
          v-model="city" name="city" 
          v-validate data-vv-rules="required">
        <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="c.id" v-for="c in cities">{{ c.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <p v-if="errors.has('city')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('city') }}</p>

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <pre>{{ errors }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ fields }}</pre>

  </div>
</body>
```

And this is the js:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Jakarta'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Depok'
    }],
    name: '',
    city: '',
    email: ''
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm: function() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(function(success) {
        if (!success) return;

        alert("All good")
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Why only the email field being validated ?

Comment: When I opened code in jsfiddle with link provided above, I found validation is working as expected in jsfiddle. It seems validation is working as expected when you start interacting with UI elements. Can you please elaborate more about exact problem ?

Comment: I got your question. Its not working when you load page and click submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In above html code when I changed error display directives from `"v-if"` to `"v-show"` then it starts working. Here is working example in the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saty2020/dqoL3b5r/2/.).

As per [VueJs Document Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)  below is comparison between `"v-if"` vs `"v-show"`.

`v-if` is lazy: **if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything - the conditional block won’t be rendered until the condition becomes true for the first time**.

In comparison, `v-show` is much simpler - the element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with just simple CSS-based toggling.

Comment: Great @saty ! its working now. Did not think the `v-if` in error message  could cause vee-validate to stop working. I thought the only required things are the `v-validate` and `data-vv-rules` attributes in the input element as stated in the [example](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/#basic-example). It said _"All you need is to add the v-validate directive to the input you wish to validate."_

Comment: @HendraSetiawan I am glad that it answer your question.